# My recycleView does not work with dropdrown selection (Android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-recyclerview, drop-down-menu

MainActivity.kt :

```
package com.example.smstest


import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri

import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Telephony
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView

import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import java.util.Date
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private fun sendSms(phoneNumber: String, message: String) {

    val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null)
}

private var titlesList = mutableListOf<String>()
private var descList = mutableListOf<String>()
private var imagesList = mutableListOf<Int>()




override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_recyclerView)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = RecyclerAdapter(titlesList,descList,imagesList)




    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,
                android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS), PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        )
    }

    val cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null)
    val num_size = cursor?.count.toString()
    var List = arrayListOf<String>("50004001151398","50004000151398")
    postToList(num_size,List[0])
    


    for(i in 0 until num_size.toInt()) {
        cursor?.moveToPosition(i)
        var sender = cursor?.getString(2)
        var text = cursor?.getString(12)
    }
    var mutableList = mutableListOf<String>()
    for(i in 1 .. 2){
        mutableList.add("سالن $i")
    }


    var j : Int = 1
    val autoComplete : AutoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.auto_complete)
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_hall,mutableList)
    autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter)
    autoComplete.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
        adapterView, view, i, l ->
        val itemSelected = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)

        j = autoComplete.text.substring(5,6).toInt() //*سالن *{1}


            postToList(num_size,List[j-1])

        Toast.makeText(this, autoComplete.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }




                val br = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
                for (sms in Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(
                    p1
                )) {
                  Toast.makeText(applicationContext,sms.displayMessageBody,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            registerReceiver(
                br,
                IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"),
                RECEIVER_EXPORTED
            )
        }



}


private fun addToList(title : String , description : String , image : Int){
    titlesList.add(title)
    descList.add(description)
    imagesList.add(image)
}

private fun postToList(num_size : String , sender_phone : String){
    val cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null)
    

    for(i in 0 until num_size.toInt()){
        cursor?.moveToPosition(i)
        var sender = cursor?.getString(2)
        var text = cursor?.getString(12)
        if(text!!.toString().length == 5 && sender == sender_phone) {
            var dateCode = cursor?.getString(4).toString()
            var date = Date(dateCode.toLong()).toString().subSequence(11,16).toString()
            addToList("Dama: ${text.subSequence(1,3)} Rotubat: ${text.subSequence(3,5)}", "Description $date", R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
        }
        else{continue}
    }
}


}
```

RecyclerAdapter.kt :

```
    package com.example.smstest
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


class RecyclerAdapter (private var titles: List<String> , private var details: List<String> , private var images: List<Int>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val itemTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_titte)
        val itemDetail: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description)
        val itemPicture: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
                val position : Int = adapterPosition
                Toast.makeText(itemView.context,"You have clicked on item # ${position+1}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return titles.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemTitle.text = titles[position]
        holder.itemDetail.text = details[position]
        holder.itemPicture.setImageResource(images[position])
    }
}
```

In MainActivity, when the execution code postToList(a,b) is outside AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{}, it works: (I have not select one item yet)

[image]

But I want my list to be shown after dropdown selection and depending his choice

And for this, I need my execution code to be inside AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{}

(It means when I start the app, there is no list to be shown; after selection, the related list must be shown)

What is the solution